# Send request through RestTemplate using UserDetails / Authentication class as basic auth

Tags: java, spring-security

I'd like to provide RestTemplate an `UserDetails` or alike class as authorization.

```
    public static ResponseEntity<List<EntityResponseDTO>> getAllEntitiesRequest(UserDetails loggedUser) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        // Credentials are shown!
        headers.setBasicAuth("admin", "admin");
        
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers); 
        var response = restTemplate
                .exchange("/api/admin/entity",
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        request,
                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<EntityResponseDTO>>() {
                        });
        return response;
    }
```

I can provide this method with an already logged user, but I don't know how to provide RestTemplate with it. Can someone point me in the right direction?